# Node module version conflict while developing package for Atom

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, atom-editor

I'm developing my first package for Atom. To do it, I need this package `nodegit`([here the official website](https://www.nodegit.org)).

When I try to run my package, I get this error:

```
The module '/Users/danny/github/branch-control/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release   
/nodegit.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I already tried to look online but none of the solutions I found solved my problem.

I tried with `npm rebuild`, `npm rebuild nodegit`, I tried to install it with `--update-binary` and I tried with different node versions, without success.

Moreover it says `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69`, but there is no version `69` in the node releases, it goes from `64` to `72` directly.

I found online that this `69` refers to the node version that electron uses, but I think I can not change it, because it's the version that Atom uses.

How can I solve this and go on?

This is my environment:

- macOS Catalina 10.15
- Atom 1.44.0

  - Electron 4.2.7
  - Chrome 69
  - Node 10.11.0

Comment: delete your `node_modules` dir, run `npm cache clean`, then rerun `npm install`, and anything that needs compiling should now recompile against whatever the node version is you're actually using. Also, you probably want to stop being on Node 10, it goes out of active support in April, with v12 being the "current" LTS version.

Comment: And you probably want to use the latest version of electron which contains the (almost) latest version of chromium with all the security fixes they applied so far.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried to clean the cache but the problem is still there. I already tried also with node 12, same problem. I don't think I can change the electron version. As I said I'm developing a Atom package, and Atom is build with that version of electron, node and chromium :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) for this.

From the README:

> This executable rebuilds native Node.js modules against the version of Node.js that your Electron project is using. This allows you to use native Node.js modules in Electron apps without your system version of Node.js matching exactly (which is often not the case, and sometimes not even possible).